# Using grep to get UUID

Tags: grep, nmcli

How can I get the `uuid` of `eth0` connection out of the output of `nmcli -p c` using `grep`?

Output of `nmcli -p c`:

```
$ nmcli -p c 
======================================================================================================================
                                                   Connection list
======================================================================================================================
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wired connection 1        <uuid>   802-3-ethernet    Mon 30 Jun 2014 01:10:38 AM IRDT  
ponyo@ponyo-pc:~$ nmcli -p c 
======================================================================================================================
                                                   Connection list
======================================================================================================================
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wired connection 1        <uuid>   802-3-ethernet
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `nmcli`'s parameters:

```
nmcli -t -f uuid c
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
$ nmcli -f NAME,UUID -p c | grep <your network card>
```

Example:

```
$ nmcli -f NAME,UUID -p c | grep p3p1
p3p1            95345734-ff3d-4888-bc8e-77a8a57ab958
```

Comment: This is literally more close to an answer to the question above (using grep). btw, the other answer is published sooner and answers the main question I had.